# Using Phonegap's Web SQL

Tags: html, cordova

I've read that Web SQL is not suggested to use and the support may be stopped at some point, so is it safe to use it in Phonegap? It looks like all of the examples use it, but I dont want to have an app out there and a new mobile OS version decide to kill it off. Any better suggestions or is it safe for the long run? Thanks